# Promisifying node.js class generator method

Tags: node.js, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm trying to promisify the the someAsyncMethod in the following code.

When I run the the code, the yielded promise of the someAsyncMethod is never resolved.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
'use strict';
var someapi = require('./lib/absenceio');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

class CompanyController {
    constructor(currentUser, parameters) {

    }
    * someAsyncMethod () {      
        return yield someapi.listReasons(); // returns a promise
    }
}

Promise.coroutine(function*(){
    var c = new CompanyController();
    Promise.promisifyAll(c);    
    var res = yield c.someAsyncMethodAsync();
    console.log('never reached');
})();
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `yield* c.someAsyncMethod()`?

Comment: yield* does the trick. didn't know about yield* What ist the difference between yield and yield* ?

Comment: It's explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*), but basically, it's used to delegate from one generator (your Promise coroutine) to another (the `someAsyncMethod` method).

Comment: thanks for the explanation. feel free to post the answer. if not I will create on in the next days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someAsyncMethod()` is a generator function, which you can't yield directly, but you can delegate to it using [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*).

So, your code becomes this:

```
var res = yield* c.someAsyncMethod();
```

No need to promisify it (I'm not even sure what Bluebird does when asked to promisify a generator function).